# How to Fix "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" using np where function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The variable i need to set constraints for is 'x'

Where x=1 while x*3*StdDev <= MADD-DD

otherwise x = (MADD-DD)/(3*StdDev)

Also, x must always be positive

Here is my code so far for this, I am getting: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

```
MADD = 0.3 #Maximum Acceptable Drawdown

HWM_LnSh = np.maximum.accumulate(data.LnSh_Ex_return) #Compute High 
Water Marker - the running maximum
DD_LnSh = (HWM - data.LnSh_Ex_return)/HWM_LnSh #Drawdown
MDD_LnSh = np.maximum.accumulate(DD_LnSh) #Maximum Drawdown

data['X_lnSh'] = np.where(3*data.annual_vol_LnSh>MADD - DD_LnSh,1,np.min(0, 
 (MADD - DD_LnSh)/(3*data.annual_vol_LnSh)))
```

My code so far , I am not sure how to fix this, let me know if additional info is needed, Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `>` on pandas Series pays attention to the pandas row and column labels.  If you want to just compare positions, do a `numpy` comparison, e.g. with `values` or `to_numpy`.

Comment: The error isn't the `np.where` itself, but in the comparison, which is performed first, `3*data.annual_vol_LnSh > MADD - DD_LnSh`.  That's what you need to test and get right.

Comment: Ok thank you@hpaulj , how would I go about testing this?